# where is the undefined in my javascript program?

Tags: javascript

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>oop</title>

    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">

        function Person() {

        }

        Person.prototype = {
            name : 'Lucy',
            age : 23,
            friends : ['Kinsey','Godwin','David'],
            sayHello: function () {
                document.write('hi,boy' + '<br><br>');
            }
        };

        var p = new Person();
        var p2= new Person();
        document.write(p.sayHello());

        p.friends.push('Berkhoom');
        document.write(p.friends + '<br><br>');
        document.write(p2.friends + '<br><br>');

    </script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**hi,boy

*undefined*Kinsey,Godwin,David,Berkhoom

Kinsey,Godwin,David,Berkhoom
**

I don't kown where the word undefined comes from? help?

[the program and result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3TZ3.png)

Comment: the output result:hi,boy

undefinedKinsey,Godwin,David,Berkhoom

Kinsey,Godwin,David,Berkhoom

Comment: Check your `p.fiends` array: `console.log(p.friends)`. I think you have first element empty (removed it?)

Comment: `undefined` is the standard return type for a function, like `sayHello`. You don't need to write the output of `sayHello`. Replace `document.write(p.sayHello());` with `p.sayHello();`

Answer (score 1):

In your actual code `undefined` comes from the line:

```
document.write(p.sayHello());
```

Because `undefined` is the default return for a `function`, and you haven't specified any `return` for your `sayHello` function.

This is a snippet where, I commented the above line showing the difference:

```js
        function Person() {

        }

        Person.prototype = {
            name : 'Lucy',
            age : 23,
            friends : ['Kinsey','Godwin','David'],
            sayHello: function () {
                document.write('hi,boy' + '<br><br>');
            }
        };

        var p = new Person();
        var p2= new Person();
        //document.write(p.sayHello());

        p.friends.push('Berkhoom');
        document.write(p.friends + '<br><br>');
        document.write(p2.friends + '<br><br>');
```

So you just need to call the function `sayHello()` instead of writing its output:

```js
function Person() {

}

Person.prototype = {
  name: 'Lucy',
  age: 23,
  friends: ['Kinsey', 'Godwin', 'David'],
  sayHello: function() {
    document.write('hi,boy' + '<br><br>');
  }
};

var p = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();
p.sayHello();

p.friends.push('Berkhoom');
document.write(p.friends + '<br><br>');
document.write(p2.friends + '<br><br>');
```

Comment: @GodwinQ You are welcome. can you please accept my answer as it helps? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(p.sayHello());
```

this is printing `undefined` 
you don't need to call document.write() here just call:

```
p.sayHello();
```